# Grails: How to test the existence of a gsp/template file from a controller?

Tags: grails, groovy, internationalization

I would like to implement the following:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils as RCU

class HomeController {
    def home = {
        def locale = RCU.getLocale(request)
        render view: viewExists("home_$locale") ? "home_$locale": "home"
    }
}
```

What is the code of `boolean viewExists(String viewPath)` that returns true if the input argument points to a valid GSP or Template file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
def uri = "test123.gsp"        
def resource = grailsAttributes.pagesTemplateEngine.getResourceForUri(uri)

if ( resource && resource.file && resource.exists() ) {
    // exists
}
```

(modified from [this post](http://oohshiny.net/post/grails-does-a-template-exist/)) but note the caveat that getResourceForUri() is private ([see here](http://github.com/grails/grails/blob/master/grails/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/pages/GroovyPagesTemplateEngine.java)). The code works for me but it doesn't give me a warm/fuzzy feeling.

I think the question is to frame your question in terms of the larger goal/problem and try to solve that. Grails probably has an answer.